# File Permission in SFTP in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sftp

I wanted to set permission for a file present sftp like read access only or read/ write access.
Currently we are using fileZilla is there any way where we can provide permission to the file in marketing cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this on a file level.
Marketing Cloud however since one of the latest releases has been giving the option of three accounts per Business Units, for which you can set those permissions.
So to a very limited degree, you can work with separating your usecases into (3) different sFTP accounts with read only / full access respectively.

Setup / Data Management / FTP accounts, on your account there is a little downward arrow which lets you change these settings:

[image]

Comment: I'm typing too slowly ;-)

Comment: Thank you @Jonas for your quick response much appreciated:)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with Marketing Cloud's SFTP - you cannot set permissions on a file level.

The only permission control that is possible in Marketing Cloud's FTP is to restrict access for a user:

[image]

You can have up to 3 users per FTP, so I would suggest creating one with full access, and a second one with read-only access.

Comment: Thank you @Zuzan for your inputs. It helped me alot